# Bad Data in linked table

Tags: casting, sql-server-2012, openquery

I pull data to SQL Server from a cobol database that is connected as a linked server. 
we have ended up with bad data in one of our tables, and I am trying to track down the offending record. specifically we have a letter entered in to a year field, when SQL pulls the data over it attempts to convert that column to a numeric data type.

I believe what I need is a combination of openquery and cast to select all columns with at least that specific column as varchar, so that I can retrieve the specific offending record and have the dept. fix the error.

I have tried the following two syntax but both produces an error.

```
select * from [incode]...ctvehl 
 where VEH_YEAR like '992D'

select * from openquery (incode, 'select cast(* as nvarchar) from ctvehl')
```

for clarity

```
 linked server name = incode
  table name = CTVEHL
  Specific offending column = VEH_YEAR
```

assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just initially insert the data into a work table within SQL Server that has all `varchar()` columns.  You could then validate and parse the work table for possible errors, moving the bad rows to an "error" table for other processing/reporting.  Then insert the remaining rows into your actual table.

You should look into SQL Server Integration Services, it offers ways to mass import data and handle bad rows, see: [SQL Server Integration Services Dealing with Bad Data](http://www.programminghelp.com/sql-server/sql-server-integration-services-dealing-with-bad-data/)

Comment: using a select into statement?

Comment: I would use something like `INSERT INTO local_WorkTable (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM openquery (incode, 'select col1, col2, col3 from from ctvehl')`.  However, you could even try to skip the WorkTable by using  `INSERT INTO local_RealTable (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, cast(col3 as varchar(23)) FROM openquery (incode, 'select col1, col2, col3 from from ctvehl')`.  Openquery passes your query to the Cobol system which doesn't seem to be able to handle the `cast`, this will make the `cast` run local on SQL Server.

Comment: ok with this code  `Create table local_tempTable
(
VEH_VEHICLE_CODE int,
VEH_YEAR varchar(23)
)
INSERT INTO local_TempTable (VEH_VEHICLE_CODE, VEH_YEAR) SELECT VEH_VEHICLE_CODE,cast(VEH_YEAR as varchar(23)) FROM openquery (incode, 'select VEH_VEHICLE_CODE, VEH_YEAR from ctvehl')`      I am still seeing this error OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "incode" returned message "[TOD][ODBC][GENESIS]VISION: Error converting field VEH_YEAR string '992D' to numeric".
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "incode".

Comment: try just selecting the data: `select * FROM openquery (incode, 'select VEH_VEHICLE_CODE, VEH_YEAR from ctvehl')`

Comment: gives the same error when it reaches that record but it looks like the veh_vehicle_code may be in numerical order... so that may help me out.

Comment: this must be a problem on the Cobol side, since you can't even select the data